# Mysql joining two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need to join the following two tables

```
table_A
id    userId    name        score   game
1      2343     me          45       Palo Alto
2      6575     other       21       SF
3      6575     other           2        miami

table_B
id  userId      pen     mango
1    2343       3       4
2   2343        5       7
3   6575        1       2
```

Here is the join:

```
SELECT COUNT(a.userId), SUM(b.pen), SUM(b.mango) 
  FROM table_A AS a 
  LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.userId = b.userId 
    WHERE userId = 2343;
```

The problem is I am getting count(userId) equals to 2, but I need it to be 1. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And why does it need to be 1? there are 2 rows in the join result before aggregation so the count is 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to the following:

```
count(distinct a.userId)
```

Comment: I got the answer immediately after posting. but I was not allowed to reply to my post. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query will gerneate two rows, each row corresponding to one row in table_B (one for id 1, one for id 2).

I am not sure why you think the resulting `count(a.userId)` should be 1, but you could enforce this by using a `GROUP BY` clause à la `GROUP BY b.userId`.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused about what you are doing. You can still get `SUM` of *Pen* and *Mango* without joining the two tables. And another thing, why do you still use the `COUNT` function where, in fact, you know that you are querying to **ONLY ONE** ID? Right?

```
SELECT SUM(Pen) as TotalPen,
       SUM(Mango) as TotalMango
FROM table_B 
WHERE userId = 2343
```

But if you want a joined tables you could write something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(b.pen,0)) as TotalPen, 
       SUM(COALESCE(b.mango,0)) as TotalMango
FROM table_A AS a LEFT JOIN table_B b ON a.userId = b.userId 
WHERE a.userId = 2343;
```

*The problem is I am getting count(userId) equals to 2, but I need it to be 1.* - The query is correct but your understanding is wrong. Obviously there are `two record IDs of 2343` in `Table_B`